# How To Find 3rd Party API On Checkout Page?

Tags: javascript, api, stripe-payments

So there is a website using 3rd party API in Stripe. When someone purchase their service, the wommerce send order to the 3rd party along with payment by taking their share. How can I find that 3rd party site API on cart page using inspect element.

I'm unable to trace the APi

Comment: did you try to look into the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

### Step By Step Solution

**1)** Open the DevTools (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, OR `Right Click` > `Inspect`)

**2)** Go to the tab `Network`

**3)** Click on the black dot in the top left corner (it will become red) OR click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Now you're ready to track/trace all the API calls that are done.

NB: Remember, this tab should be opened before the call is done

[image]

You can even filter the calls (if there's plenty of them) by typing any relevant keyword in the search bar

[image]

Comment: Yes, I tried but there are many scripts coming. For example, if you see this page ( boosthill. com/checkout/) they are using a third party API and I want to know which SMM panel API is that.

Comment: I updated the answer. Kindly check it